# Solving $xy+z=a$, $x+y=b$, $yz=c$. Is there a trick to avoid a cubic?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

How may one solve this system?

$$\begin{align}
xy+z &=a \\ 
x+y  &=b \\ 
yz   &=c
\end{align}$$

It keeps leading to a cubic in one of the variables when you apply direct substitution, which is tedious to solve. Is there a way to circumvent this? Some trick?

Many thanks.

Comment: Since $a,b,c$ don't have restrictions, maybe the only solution you will find is that cubic equation.

Comment: For example, when $a=b=0$, then all solutions are given by $(x,y,z)=(t,-t,t^2)$, where $t$ is any cube root of $-c$, so there's no avoiding a cubic.

Comment: @quasi: This is not a proof, just some evidence. For example $x(x-1)(x-2)=0$ has three roots but one does not need Cardano to find them.

Comment: As in the first comment, unless there is more information about $a,b,c$, it's essentially a general cubic.

Comment: I would find a Groebner basis of this system of equations. It probably will contain a cubic indecomposable polynomial in one variable. This would show that Cardano is inevitable.

Comment: No need for Groebner bases. By simple substitutions, one can find if-and-only-if irreducible (irreducible for _unknown_ $a,b,c$) univariate cubic equations for $x,y$. In any case, it suffices to exhibit a single choice of $a,b,c$ (such as $a=0,b=0,c=2$) which yields irreducible univariate cubics for $x,y,z$. Bottom line: There's no trick.